# If I click on button in quick succession, it causes text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below I have a checkbox which is styled like a button:

```
 echo '<p>';
 foreach($options as $indivOption) {
     echo '<div id="ck-button"><label><input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-' . $indivOption . '" value="' . $indivOption . '" /><span>' . $indivOption . '</span></label></div>';
 }
  echo '</p>';
```

Now what happens is that if I click on the checkbox button quickly twice, it turns on the button but then it does not turn it off, it instead does a little text selection on the button. So if I have button known as `E`, if I click it twice quickly, it turns the button on and then it highlights the letter `E`.

My question is that for only the checkbox buttons, how in javascript as I assume it is client side to sort this out, how to prevent the text selection from happening only for the checkbox buttons, not for the whole document.

Thanks

Comment: CSS styles to prevent selection are listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting). Maybe that will help.

Comment: It could be easier to read if you put the generated code, instead of the php code

Comment: Why not just make it a real button that updates a hidden checkbox, since that's what you really want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply this style to the check buttons (or, in your case, the div containing the check buttons):

```
#ck-button {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

For browsers < IE10, add the property `onselectstart="return false;"` to the `ck-button` div.

Comment: Should mention, as far as I know this is only supported in IE10+

Comment: @joeltine: Good point, updating answer.